# Is this possible to check if a broadcast was sent in sticky mode? Can it be aborted/removed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is this possible to check if a broadcast was sent in sticky mode?

Can we completely abort/remove a sticky broadcast? If yes, then can it be done for both normal and ordered broadcasts?

Comment: Sticky broadcasts can be removed; see ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839043/android-how-can-i-completely-abort-remove-sticky-broadcast

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `onReceive()` you can use the following calls:

`isInitialStickyBroadcast()` - This will tell you if the broadcast you are currently processing was sent as "sticky" and was the current one when the `BroadcastReceiver` was registered.

`isOrderedBroadcast()` - This will tell you if the broadcast you are currently processing was sent as an "ordered" broadcast.

If you just want to see if there is a "sticky" broadcast, you can call

```
registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)
```

and supply `null` as the `receiver` parameter. This will return any "sticky" broadcast without actually registering the receiver.

You can remove a sticky broadcast using:

```
removeStickyBroadcast(Intent intent)
```

However, IMHO that would be counter-productive. Usually "sticky" broadcasts are sent to indicate the **current state** of something. So removing it would imply that it isn't possible for an application to determine the current state.