# Android: How can I completely abort/remove sticky broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

We can remove an **ordered broadcast** with `abortBroadcast()`, is there a way to completely remove a **sticky ordered broadcast**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`removeStickyBroadcast` is exactly what you need:

```
public abstract void removeStickyBroadcast (Intent intent)
```

> **Since**: API Level 1
>
> Remove the data previously sent with `sendStickyBroadcast(Intent)`, so that it is as if the sticky broadcast had never happened.
>
> You must hold the `BROADCAST_STICKY` permission in order to use this API. If you do not hold that permission, SecurityException will be thrown.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *intent*   The Intent that was previously broadcast.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#removeStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)