# Android broadcast receiver, receive a broadcast every time when app launched

Tags: android, service, callback, bind, broadcast

In my main activity i bind a service.

```
    //main activity class
    public void startNotificationService(){
    // add notice service
    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(appContext,NotificationService.class);
    appContext.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

when the service is created a broadcast receiver is registered, so when ever Android framework send a broadcast the service can catch it and push a notification.

```
    // service class
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    handlerMessage = new UnsolicitedMessageHandler();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("disassociation");
    intentFilter.addAction("remediation");
    registerReceiver(new UnsolicitedMessageHandler (), intentFilter);
}
```

the following is the handle class of the broadcast receiver

```
class UnsolicitedMessageHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String message;
            if (action.equals("disassociation")) {
                message = intent.getStringExtra("frameName");
                showNotification(R.drawable.disconnect,
                        "Disassocation Notification", message);
            }
            if (action.equals("remediation")) {
                message = intent.getStringExtra("remMsg");
                showNotification(R.drawable.scan, "Remediation Notification",
                        message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, the problem is that every time when i kill the app and lunches it again, a broadcast is received by UnsolicitedMessageHandler(i know, the system absolutely don't send a broadcast)
It's really confusing and frustration. Anyone can help me? Thanks in adnvance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because whenever you kill and start your app again you receive STICKY brodcast.

In onReceive use isInitialStickyBroadcast() to check if current brodcast you are processing is STICKY. If that is STICKY then just ignore and do no processing

Comment: I found one good answer on how to remove STICKY intents here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839043/android-how-can-i-completely-abort-remove-sticky-broadcast. If your case is of STICKY intents then use one of solution mentioned in link

Comment: Thank you very much  Changdeo Jadhav, you saved my day!!!!! for my case, the sticky broadcast is actually sent by myself(i modified the Android framework class, send the sticky broadcast there), so i can just modify it to a common broadcast the problem should be solved. and i should have good a study on what the sticky broadcast is.Thank you!